# Как отозвать все access token-ы конкретного пользователя в laravel passport?

Tags: php, laravel

Допустим у меня есть такая теоретическая ситуация, что мне необходимо отозвать все access token-ы конкретного пользователя, по какой-то его манипуляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитав английский stackoverflow и по шерстив google не найдя полного ответа пришел к такому варианту.

```
\DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')
            ->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('revoked', '<>', 1)
            ->update(['revoked' => 1]);
```

Были варианты делать что то подобное с помощью \Auth::user()->tokens, но там производилось множество запросов к БД, потому склонен считать выбранный вариант более экономичным.